# Understanding a Text.Regex.Posix design choice

Tags: regex, haskell, module

I was playing around a bit with `Text.Regex.Posix`, and I found this strange design choice.

This was my GHCi session:

```
λ> "Needle, Haystack, foo, and bar." =~ "[^ ]+" :: String
"Needle,"
λ> "Needle, Haystack, foo, and bar." =~ "[^ ]+" :: [[String]]
[["Needle,"],["Haystack,"],["foo,"],["and"],["bar."]]
λ> "Needle, Haystack, foo, and bar." =~ "[^ ]+" :: [String]

<interactive>:27:35:
    No instance for (RegexContext Regex [Char] [String])
      arising from a use of ‘=~’
    In the expression:
        "Needle, Haystack, foo, and bar." =~ "[^ ]+" :: [String]
    In an equation for ‘it’:
        it = "Needle, Haystack, foo, and bar." =~ "[^ ]+" :: [String]
```

I was suprised to find that, in the instances of `RegexContext`, there was no instance for `RegexLike a b => RegexContext a b [b]`, but only `RegexLike a b => RegexContext a b [[b]]`.

I cannot understand why this design has been used. Why is there no instance for `[String]` as described above, and why is it instead only `[[String]]`?

Comment: Try `getAllTextMatches $ "Needle, Haystack, foo, and bar." =~ "[^ ]+" :: [String]`.

Comment: @stribizhev That's all good, but why not just make an instance for `[String]` instead of making us use `getAllTextMatches`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That instance *did* exist in `Text.Regex.Base.Context` back in [`regex-base-0.83`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-base-0.83) (uploaded March 5, 2007), but was removed in [`regex-base-0.90`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-base-0.90) (uploaded March 13, 2007). There is no changelog or explanation (and the module documentation at this point has a `XXX THIS HADDOCK DOCUMENTATION IS OUT OF DATE XXX` comment that remains until the current version.)

However, my best *guess* as to why it was done is the fact that `String` is a type synonym for `[Char]`, so that having instances for both `String` and `[b]` would lead to overlapping instance problems - I think not directly, but enough to make type inference work badly, especially if you're using `OverloadedStrings` (although I don't know if that extension already existed back then).